# convert buffer from database to string

Tags: node.js

I stored an buffer in database.
I have an buffer like this (from database):

```
{
    data =     (
        76,
        39,
        65,
        77,
        66,
        65,
        83,
        83,
        65,
        68,
        79,
        82
    );
    type = Buffer;
}
```

I'd like to convert it to string, but it is not working.
I tried with .toString('utf8');

```
console.log(buffer.toString('utf8');
```

I get :

```
{"type":"Buffer","data":[123,10,32,32,32,32,100,97,116,97,32,61,32,32,32,32,32,40,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,55,54,44,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,51,57,44,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,54,53,44,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,55,55,44,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,54,54,44,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,54,53,44,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,56,51,44,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,56,51,44,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,54,53,44,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,54,56,44,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,55,57,44,10,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,32,56,50,10,32,32,32,32,41,59,10,32,32,32,32,116,121,112,101,32,61,32,66,117,102,102,101,114,59,10,125]}
```

What's wrong in this? How can I get the value of this buffer?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] as right now it's very confusing what you have, your code example looks like javascript or whatnot, but you claim it is "from database", then you show json that doesn't match the example. Can you please be explicit what you have and what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Buffer.from(array)`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array) syntax.

```
const data = [76,39,65,77,66,65,83,83,65,68,79,82];
const buf = Buffer.from(data)
const str = buf.toString();
console.log('str',str); // outputs L'AMBASSADOR
```